# VBA Macro to Upload WordPress Content without Using SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a VBA macro that will log into my WordPress site, go to the Add New Post section, click the Code Editor and then add the blocks of HTML code (which is a range of cells).

The issue is that I am adding a very large block of content (35,000 characters), so when I use SendKeys it either takes a really long time (like 10 minutes) and often it crashes with a timeout error. I have also tried creating a loop that creates a string with all my content from each row and then clicking on the form field and pasting it, but it runs into the same problem.

Now I have tried just creating an HTMLDocument so I can set the value of the text field directly, as shown in the following code (I am trying to do this in the line that reads MyBrowser.FindElementById("post-content-0").Value = contentbloI am trying to create a VBA macro that will log into my WordPress site, go to the Add New Post section, click the Code Editor and then add the blocks of HTML code (which is a range of cells).

The issue is that I am adding a very large block of content (35,000 characters), so when I use SendKeys it either takes a really long time (like 10 minutes) and often it crashes with a timeout error. I have also tried creating a loop that creates a string with all my content from each row and then clicking on the form field and pasting it, but it runs into the same problem.

Now I have tried just creating an HTMLDocument so I can set the value of the text field directly, as shown in the following code (I am trying to do this in the line that reads MyBrowser.FindElementById("post-content-0").Value = contentblock). I am not able to get it to work though. I have found some guides that show how this can be done with IE but not sure if it is different with chrome.

I have tried setting the HTMLdocument with Set page = MyBrowser.PageSource and Set page = MyBrowser.Document but I get errors that it doesn't support this property or there is a type mismatch. I have the HTML Object Library installed so that shouldn't be the issue.

Here is the following code:

```
Option Explicit
   
Dim MyBrowser As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
   
Sub UploadWordPress()
   
   Dim i
   Dim WshShell
   Dim contentblock
   Dim page As Object
   Dim articlebody As Object
   
   MyBrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://mysitename.com"
   MyBrowser.Get "https://mysitename.com/wp-admin"
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
   MyBrowser.FindElementById("user_login").SendKeys "My WordPress User Name"
   MyBrowser.FindElementByName("pwd").SendKeys "My WordPress Password"
   MyBrowser.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/form/p[3]/input[1]").Click
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 8, Now)
   
   MyBrowser.Get "https://ccdigitalcontent.com/wp-admin/post-new.php"
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
   Set page = MyBrowser.PageSource
   
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
   
   contentblock = Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Text
   For i = 2 To 40
   
   contentblock = contentblock & Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
   
   Next
   
   Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
   WshShell.SendKeys "^+%M"
   MyBrowser.FindElementById("post-content-0").Value = contentblock
   
   End Sub
```